# How can I ensure the ids for the new Students is unique

Tags: java, io, hashmap, hashset, bluej

I have reading a file which set the ids to unknown and i have creating a uniqe id for each student and I wrote then to a file, for example if create Student  and add it to the list (HashMap).  How can i be sure that the id that has been allocated for the new Student has not already been allocated to one of the Student in the file Student_data.txt ?
How can I ensure the ids for the new Students when I ass them are not in the txt file which contains the old added student to the hashMap

Comment: What kind of IDs are you using?

Comment: `nextId = 1;`  `addStudent() { hashmap.add(student, nextID++) }` Just always increment `nextID`, and have the `nextID` be persistent.

Comment: ids generteded by the Random class for example "AB-1212", shall I provide you the method

Comment: I think I have to read the file first and then maybe to store it in a local variable and then compare it with the new Id which generted for a new student but I am not sure how to do this thanks

Comment: I suggest that you read in the existing IDs from the .txt, and then use `containsKey()` to check if the key already exists. Hard to give a good advice without seeing your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a SHA-1 out of the student's name or some other field and use that as a key?

```
static HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.sha1();
public static byte[] getHash(final String name) {
  HashCode hashCode = hashFunction.newHasher().putBytes(name.getBytes).hash();
  return hashCode.asBytes();
}
```

I used the Google library to do this, you can use `MessageDigest` as well, but its not thread safe.

To read hash

```
System.out.println("Hash is: " + new String(Hex.encodeHex(hashInByte)));
```

The output would be something like this:

```
Hash is: ff56b9948d201ee37605e101e01f63aab97b5e4a
```

Comment: But i want to read the file and store and compare it with the new genereted id

Comment: Of course you can do this. Just read the hash as a Hex. Ill update